# How to use SCNSceneSource method entryWithIdentifier:classType:?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to extract animations from a DAE file, how do I use this method in swift?

Thanks,

Objective-C code is:

//CAAnimation *animation = [sceneSource entryWithIdentifier:animationIDs[index] withClass:[CAAnimation class]];

```
func extractAnimationsFromSceneSource(sceneSource: SCNSceneSource) {

    let animationsIDs: NSArray = [sceneSource.isKindOfClass(CAAnimation)]

    let animationCount: Int = animationsIDs.count
    var longAnimations = NSMutableArray(capacity: animationCount)

    let maxDuration: CFTimeInterval = 0

    for index in 0..animationCount {
// gets error CAAnimation is not convertible to 'AnyClass'
        let animation = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier(animationsIDs[index], withClass:CAAnimation())
    }

}
```

Comment: @David Rönnqvist thanks, with: let animation = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier(animationsIDs[index], withClass:CAAnimation) I get error "Cannot convert the expression's type 'CAAnimation' to type '$T7'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues you'll need to deal with here:

- The Swift equivalent of `[SomeClass class]` is `SomeClass.self`.
- Because `entryWithIdentifier` returns an `id` in ObjC, you'll typically want to cast it to an appropriate Swift type (because you can't call methods or access properties on an `AnyObject`).
- `entryWithIdentifier` can return `nil` in ObjC if no entry is found, which means it returns an optional in Swift. Bridging makes that an implicitly unwrapped optional, which puts you one step away from a crash if you're planning to add these animations to an array or otherwise use them — best to check the optional yourself.

Also, your array of `animationIDs` looks suspect — you're assigning an array with one element, a Boolean that's the result of asking the scene source what class it is. (And this Boolean is always `false`, because an `SCNSceneSource` is not a kind of `CAAnimation`.)

So, your method might look something like this:

```
func extractAnimationsFromSceneSource(sceneSource: SCNSceneSource) {

    let animationsIDs = source.identifiersOfEntriesWithClass(CAAnimation.self) as String[]
    var animations: CAAnimation[] = []
    for animationID in animationsIDs {
        if let animation = source.entryWithIdentifier(animationID, withClass: CAAnimation.self) as? CAAnimation {
            animations += animation
        }
    }

}
```

(Includes a bit of attempting to infer your intent, and slimming code down where type inference allows such.)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm still trying to understand why the "as String[]" to create the array animationsIDs

Comment: You want `animationID` (in the loop) to be a `String` (or `NSString`) for passing to the first parameter of `entryWithIdentifier`. You could cast it in the loop, but it's more concise to cast the array the loop iterates over first.